# How to tune akka thread pool to reject new tasks on full thread pool and task queue?

Tags: multithreading, scala, akka, threadpool

I want to use akka thread pool to perform some parallel tasks with limited resources and if there are too many tasks I want them to be rejected.

I have the following dispatcher configured with akka

```
my-dispatcher {
  type = Dispatcher
  executor = thread-pool-executor
  thread-pool-executor {
    core-pool-size-min = 1
    core-pool-size-max = 2
    task-queue-size = 5
  }
}
```

And the following code

```
import java.time.LocalTime

import akka.actor.ActorSystem

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val system = ActorSystem("my-system")
    implicit val dispatcher = system.dispatchers.lookup("my-dispatcher")

    for (_ <- 1 to 10) Future {
      Thread.sleep(5000)
      println(s"Finished at ${ LocalTime.now }")
    }

    Await.result(system.terminate(), Duration.Inf)
  }

}
```

I expected that after the thread pool has running out free threads (maximum size is 2) and task-queue is also full (5 elements) - it will reject new Futures. However, that's what I see:

```
Finished at 17:36:57.858
Finished at 17:36:57.858
Finished at 17:36:57.858
Finished at 17:36:57.858
Finished at 17:36:57.858
Finished at 17:37:02.870
Finished at 17:37:02.870
Finished at 17:37:02.870
Finished at 17:37:02.870
Finished at 17:37:02.870
```

Thus, it invokes first 5 tasks, finishes them almost at the same time (17:36:57), and after a pause of 5 seconds (`Thread.sleep(5000)`) at 17:37:02 finishes the second portion of tasks. It means that when queue is full and thread pool is completely busy - instead of rejecting new futures the `Future.apply(???)` invocation just blocks. I want to see some sort of RejectionException or similar.

How to achieve this behaviour with akka?

Comment: I think you can use a NonBlockingBoundedMailbox for mailbox, and limit it to your number of threads (or 0, I'm not totally sure ^^ of the semantic :D )

Comment: I have the same question. Have you found a solution?

Comment: I am afraid I didn't. The only thing I can offer - to use any thread pool (from java.util.concurrent.*) directly, convert to ExecutionContext if needed.